# Angular Router doesn't redirect from base path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make my first multi-module angular project work. My main app routing looks like this :

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppWithHeaderComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppBlankComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'authentication',
        loadChildren: () => import('./authentication/authentication.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I expect that if i open the base path (localhost:4200) it redirects me to /dashboard, but that does not happen. I just see the blank screen of the main app.component, no errors in console log.

I have narrowed it down to this, so separate modules don't mix up anything :

```
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent
  }
```

but it still does not do anything.
In both cases, if i type in /dashboard manually, it opens the component correctly.

I have also tried debugging with

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes,{ enableTracing: true })
```

But the only useful thing i see in it is that the url is really not redirected:

```
url: "/"
urlAfterRedirects: "/"
```

I have run out of ideas, because this works flawlessly in another project, and it should do here aswell.
Any help or clue appreciated! :)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so the problem was that my AuthenticationModule, which contains login component with routing, was also imported into app.module, because I wanted to use AuthGuard, which is also placed in my AuthenticationModule.

The routing of authentication module is like this :

```
{
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

now THIS empty path was overriding the app.module's routing for empty path, so thats why it did not work.

For now, i have moved auth.guard out of AuthenticationModule, so it is now OK, but is there a solution to use it like that? ( order of imports in app.module didn't make any change )

Comment: can you recreate the issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: make sure that you are not having like this:-  /<some blank>/ dashboard
As routes cannot be blank url.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with `{ path: "'', component: AppBlankComponent }` because `patchMatch` is `prefix` by default, which makes the route to be valid every time.

Comment: @Koocka Thank you for the update, your problem was the same one I had (another routing module imported that had an empty path defined, which was overriding the top level one)